# Will these two regex give me the same desired output?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a regex for validating input.
I would like to process only the first part (up to \s).
Will the second line do the job, or am I missing something?

my research on regex101.com shows it matches the same text.

Original:

```
input.matches("^NOT\\s+.*"))
```

and Modified:

```
input.startsWith("NOT\\s")
```

this was done to avoid https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html
according to sonar.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the first regex? Note `+` does not make sense there and `^` is redundant, `input.matches("NOT\\s.*"))` will do the same job.

Comment: Is this about Java `matches` and `startsWith`? Then maybe tag accordingly...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I don't understand why `^` is redundant, care to explain?

Comment: @PoulBak In Java, `String#matches` requires a full string match, `\A` and `\z` anchors are applied automatically.

Comment: Note that the argument for `String.startsWith` ISN'T a regular expression so no, they are not the same

Answer (score 0):

The [OWASP page](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS) describes evil regexes as those that contain

> - Grouping with repetition
> - Inside the repeated group:
>
>   - Repetition
>   - Alternation with overlapping

which is not always right. Their examples are good, but the rules are too generic and even good and safe patterns can be trigger the vulnerability

You can actually remove the first `+` to stop the warning from showing:

```java
input.matches("NOT\\s.*")
```

This way, only one `*` is used.